# get broken excel file from Spring server

Tags: angularjs, spring, client-server

really don't now what to do.

i have on my server xls file and i wont to download it from my client.

i actually do it but the file getting in some weird langue and absolutely broken.

client : `angular`

server: `spring 4`

## Code

**Client**

```
function getXCEL() {
        self.onXCELProcess = true;
        AdminService.getXL(MotherService.getAppMember())
            .then(
                function (response) {

                    var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/excel'});

                    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
                    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
                    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

                    if (isChrome){
                        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                        var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                        downloadLink.attr('href',url.createObjectURL(file));
                        downloadLink.attr('target','_self');
                        downloadLink.attr('download', 'yourReports.xls');
                        downloadLink[0].click();
                    }
                    else if(isEdge || isIE){
                        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file,'yourReports.xls');

                    }
                    else {
                        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        window.open(fileURL);
                    }

                    self.onXCELProcess = false;
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.error("error : "+error+" , error : "+JSON.stringify(error));
                    self.onXCELProcess = false;
                }
            )
    }






function getXL(admin) {
        return MotherService.callToServer({method: 'POST', url: URL + "orderxl", appMember: admin});
    }
```

`callToServer()` method do request, with json body. and return the `deferred.promise`
for use of `then`.

**server**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/"+Request.ADMIN_PATH+"/"+Request.ORDER_XL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getFile(@RequestBody OrderXLRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            File file = orderXLService.execute(request).getFile(); //get the file. already saved and ready to send

            try{
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "excelfilename.xlsx");
                response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                try {
                    FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception in file download :"+e);
            }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

thank you very much for any help or suggestion

Comment: Can you open the file if you use something like Postman, PowerShell? PowerShell -> Invoke-Webrequest -Uri (api) -Method Post -OutFile file.xlsx?

Comment: good idea. i use restlet rest client. result : THE TYPE OF THE RESPONSE BODY IS UNKNOWN is appear. and the file download ok.